# Android development: how to dismiss ProgreassDialog when data loading's done with multi-threading

Tags: android, android-activity

In my project, I have to load a lot data from sqlite database, then I guess the best idea would be showing a progress dialog and loading the data wanted in another thread. I make it like the codes below.

The result is that the app always crashes..... I guess the problem might be the multi-threading stuff. Probably I didn't use multi-threading mechanism or progress dialog in the correct way.

Could anybody give me any suggestions?

```
private ProgressDialog loadingDialog;

.....

    loadingDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    loadingDialog.setMessage("Loading");
    loadingDialog.setCancelable(false);

    loadingDialog.show();
    new Thread(new LoadPointsProcess()).start();

.....

public class LoadPointsProcess implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run(){
        CreateRoutePoint(); // Load data for points
        isLoadPointsDone = true;

    }
}



 CreateRoutePoint(){
   .....    // Code for loading data from database        
   loadingDialog.dismiss(); // Dismiss the dialog

}
```

Comment: you need to make sure that .dismiss() method is always called from the UI thread. In your case you are calling `CreateRoutePoint()` which calls the `dismiss()` method, inside the `run()` of the `LoadPOintsProcess` which I assume is the runnable you pass to a different thread object

Comment: I just deleted all usages of loadingDialog, the app still crashes. Is there anything wrong with multi-threading, probably?

Comment: you need to add the error stacktrace here for me to help you further

Comment: @Bhargav Hi, Bhargav. Hours ago, I finally found the bug out by viewing the log. Actually, there was a function of an API doesn't allow to be applied after a thread finished. Then I replaced it, and the program runs like a charm now. Thanks anyway!!!!